# Login page won't redirect to the main activity page

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The following is code related to a login page but for some reason after logging in it redirects me to the registration page instead of the main activity which is stated in the code. I've also noticed that "new View.OnClickListener()" and "new OnCompleteListener()" is greyed out but I'm not sure what the effects of that are. Thanks in advance for the assistance.
Login.java:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mEmail,mPassword;
    Button mLoginBtn;
    TextView mCreateBtn;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        mCreateBtn = findViewById(R.id.createText);

        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    mEmail.setError("Email is Required");
                    return;
                }

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    mPassword.setError("Password is Required");
                    return;
                }

                if(password.length() < 6){
                    mPassword.setError("Password Must be Greater Than 6 Characters");
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate the user

                fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class));
                }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_login.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abril_fatface"
        android:text="Team D.4"
        android:textColor="#0C0C0C"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abril_fatface"
        android:text="Sign in to your Account"
        android:textColor="#0E0E0E"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17000002" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Email" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Password" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/createText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="New Here? Create Account"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginBtn" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createText" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_registration.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    tools:context=".Register">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abril_fatface"
        android:text="Team D.4"
        android:textColor="#0C0C0C"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/abril_fatface"
        android:text="Create New Account"
        android:textColor="#0E0E0E"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fullName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17000002" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fullName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Phone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:inputType="textPhonetic"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Phone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/createText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Already Registered? Login Here"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerBtn" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createText" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Registration.java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mFullName, mEmail, mPassword, mPhone;
    Button mRegisterBtn;
    TextView mLoginBtn;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mFullName = findViewById(R.id.fullName);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        mPhone = findViewById(R.id.Phone);
        mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
        mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.createText);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                mEmail.setError("Email is Required");
                return;
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                mPassword.setError("Password is Required");
                return;
            }

            if(password.length() < 6){
                mPassword.setError("Password Must be Greater Than 6 Characters");
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //register the user in firebase

            fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

        });


        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class)));
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:onClick="logout"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainAcitivity.java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void logout(View view) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(); //logout user
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of getApplicationContext() use Login.this

Comment: It is greyed out just like that the IDE tells to replace with lambda but its not a problem

Comment: @MohammedAbidNafi...Thank you for your response! I'm fairly new to this...This is the new line of code I entered based on your recommendation "startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));"...is his what you meant? I tried but the same problem is still occurring.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant hmmm can you post your Main activity and RegisterActivity XML Files not java XML files?

Comment: Actually if possible Java Files too

Comment: `TextView mCreateBtn;` - is this correct? If yes, then any specific reason you have a `clickListener` on this? Not saying its wrong but the naming and the handling is a little strange. You think this might be an issue?
For the `context` in `startActivity`, you can just use `this`.
I would also check the code in your `MainActivity` to see if the layout your are inflating is not the same as your `Register` activity. Copy-paste issues maybe...

Comment: @MohammedAbidNafi I just added the codes as requested!

Answer (score 0):

So first of all the way you login itself wont work.[1]if you add conditions that password should be n length and all after all those conditions under else statement you should login your user.And at the same time do the same with register activity too. [2] And next thing I have added some flags to the intent so this will clear out all the previous activity which may prevent your app to go to register activity after clicking login try that if that doesn't work do let me know.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText mEmail,mPassword;
Button mLoginBtn;
TextView mCreateBtn;
ProgressBar progressBar;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.Password);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    mCreateBtn = findViewById(R.id.createText);

    mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                mEmail.setError("Email is Required");
                return;
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                mPassword.setError("Password is Required");
                return;
            }

            if(password.length() < 6){
                mPassword.setError("Password Must be Greater Than 6 Characters");
                return;
            } else{                   //[1]
               loginuser();
               progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
            }
    });
             

                         


    mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class));
            }
    });

}

private void loginuser(String email, String password){
       [2]
       fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
         }
    }
```